# PublishQueueStats.aspx 500 error: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. Value cannot be null. Parameter name: item

Tags: security, admin-pages, sitecore-managed-cloud

In my 10.2 headless Managed Cloud solution, when I try to view the `/sitecore/admin/PublishQueueStats.aspx` page, I get a 500 error:

```
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: item
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.ApplySecurity(Item item, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.GetRootItem(Language language, Version version, Database database)
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.ResolvePathCommand.ResolvePath(String itemPath, Database database)
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.ResolvePathCommand.Execute(String itemPath, Database database)
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.GetItem(String itemPath, Language language, Version version, Database database, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.GetItem(String itemPath, Language language, Version version, Database database)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.GetItem(String itemPath, Language language, Version version, Database database)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceContentManagement.Administration.PublishQueueStats.GetPublishingTargets(Database database)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceContentManagement.Administration.PublishQueueStats.ReloadStatistics()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

This only seems to happen in my PROD environment, and I do recall this working before.

Comment: Do you have any custom publishing targets or additional security restrictions for the folder `/sitecore/system/publishing targets`? Looking at the stack trace,  the page tries to get all publishing targets in the method `GetPublishingTargets()` and fails to read an item.